# How to apply jackson-databind deserializer on map key?

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

I have the following field:

```
@JsonProperty("data")
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomJsonDateDeserializer.class)
private HashMap<Date,String> data;
```

I want to apply `CustomJsonDateDeserializer` only on map keys.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why dont you just add `@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomJsonDateDeserializer.class)` above Data class?

Comment: It will still not work for map keys that way. Please see the solution posted below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After carefully reading the documentation, I found the solution to my problem.

```
@JsonProperty("data")
@JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = CustomJsonDateDeserializer.class, keyAs = Date.class)
private HashMap<Date,String> data;
```

`CustomJsonDateDeserializer` has to extend the `KeyDeserializer` class.